# How to find a div that contains modal data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

BACKGROUND:

Before a product gets added into the checkout chart, I need to fire a modal window which will have customisation options. Only after this event the item should be added into the chart. I can achive this function if I use other language (c#), but I like to learn more JQuery and JQuery UI.

PROBLEM:

I have tried various ways to allocate the container with the data but so far all my methods have failed. So I have simplified the program a little as the HTML side is around 2000 lines of code and I don't like to bore you guys. Please ignore any silly mistakes like extra markup tags and missing closing tags as I tried to shorten the problem from the original source and may have missed some stuff out.

Partial HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>       
    <body>
    <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix" style="height:100%; float:left !important; border:2px solid Black;">

    <center>
    <div class="optionsHeader" style="">RECOMMENDED VALUE PACKAGES</div></center><br />
    <ul id="options" class="options ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" id="100400" title="Please view product details for handle preferences before sellecting this option.">
    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Option 1</h5>
            <font class="repairDetails" alt="Repair Details" style="">REHANDLE<br />FULL BLADE/TOE<br />REPAIR/REFURB</font>
            <font style="color:Red; text-decoration:blink; font-size:0.7em; bottom:10;">Please view product details for <u>handle preferences</u> before sellecting this option.
            </font><br />
      <label class="price">£49.99</label>
            <a class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench dialog_but" title="View Product Detail" href="#" style="">View Product Detail</a>
              <div class="dialog_content" title="" style="">

                <div id="products">
                <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Avaliable Bundle Options</h1>
                <font>You can customise this option below</font>

                <div id="pOptions">
                    <h2><a href="#">Handle</a></h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h2><a href="#">Blade</a></h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h2><a href="#">Grips</a></h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<div id="cart">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Sellected Options</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>
            <li class="placeholder"><i>Drag & Drop</i> your bat repair here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

                </div>
            <a href="" title="Add to chart" class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart chart_but">Add to chart</a>

</li>


 </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="chart" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
  <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>Repair Options       You Have Chosen</h4>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Partial JQuery:

```
   $(function() {
// there's the options and the chart
var $options = $("#options"),
    $chart = $("#chart");


//Add to chart
var recycle_icon = "<a href='' title='Remove this option' class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w'>Remove Option</a>";

function addToChart($item) {
 // He is where i need to prompt the modal than continue as below;



    $item.fadeOut(function() {
        var $list = $("ul", $chart).length ? $("ul", $chart) : $("<ul class='options     <ui-helper->  </ui-helper->reset'/>").appendTo($chart);

        $item.find("a.ui-icon-cart").remove();
        $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
            $item.animate({
                width: "100%px",
                height: "100%px"
            }) //Box
            .find("font").animate({}); //Font
        });
    });
}

// revert frm chart function
var chart_icon = "<a href='' title='Add this option' class='ui-icon ui-icon-cart'>Add Option</a>";

function revertFrmChart($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
        $item.find("a.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w").remove().end().css("width", "100%px").append(chart_icon).find("font").css("height", "100%px").end().appendTo($options).fadeIn();
    });
}

// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
$("ul.options > li").click(function(event) {
    var $item = $(this),
        $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-cart")) {
        addToChart($item);
    } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w")) {
        revertFrmChart($item);
    }

    return false;
     });
    });


   //do when the dom is ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//loop through every button anchor element
$('.dialog_but').each(function() {
    //create a local scope of a dialog variable to attach
    var $dialog;

    //create the dialog for the div.dialog_content standing next to the anchor element
    //I set the autoOpen false so that it can be reusable later
    //also I set the modal = true to appear the dialog as a modal prompt
    $dialog = $(this).next('div.dialog_content').dialog({
        title: 'Product Detail',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade'
    });

    //Swapped this with the inline version
    //add a wee bit of button thing
    //                    $(this).button({
    //                        icons: {
    //                            primary: 'ui-icon-info'
    //                        }
    //                    });
    //now attach the open event of the dialog to the anchor element
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        //prevent the anchor element to go to the hyperlinked page
        e.preventDefault();

        //open the dialog
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }); //done
});
   });




    //Modal window to ask and submit additional user details
   $(function() {
   var hShape = $("#hShape"),
    hSize = $("#hSize"),
    hType = $("#hType"),

    allFields = $([]).add(hShape).add(hSize).add(hType),
    tips = $(".validateTips");

$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    buttons: {
        "Add Details": function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(hShape, "Handle Shape", 3);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(hSize, "Handle Size", 1);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(hType, "Handle Type", 3);
            // find relevant parent element
            var $el = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');

            if (bValid) {
                // set the context to the visible div in the background -
                $('#addHere', $el.prevAll('.ui-dialog:visible')).append("<tr>" + "<td>" + hShape.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + hSize.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + hType.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>")
            }
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

$("#handle-pre").live("click", function() {

    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
   });
```

JSFiddle :

If you click on the wrench icon you will be prompted with a modal. This is the modal I need to fire when the user clicks on the add to chart.

[LINK](http://www.jsfiddle.net/7g5bC/7/)

Comment: you're looking for a callback event on the modal close?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot get the modal to fire in the first place. On the callback even of the modal close I was going to execute the code for adding to the chart. Need to fire the modal before the item is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusing bit is to pin point each modal data div for each product. So gave each modal data div a unique IDs and on add to chart i added an switch statement to fire correct modals.

So the HTML where the modal data is now have a ID;

```
    <div id="op1Dialog" class="dialog_content" title="" style="">
```

And the add to chat is now have the following;

```
   function addToChart($item) {
            var currentId = $item.attr('id');

                    switch(currentId) {
                      case "100400": $('#op1Dialog').dialog('open');  break;
                      case "100401": $('#op2Dialog').dialog('open'); break;
                      and so on...
                    }
                 Rest of the function obove..............
```

(EDIT) FIDDLE [LINK](http://www.jsfiddle.net/7g5bC/8/)

Let me know if anyone can think of a better way than using a switch statement...